# Javascript WebSocket - Need more delay

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, stm32

***I need to delay when the handshake starts when using the WebSocket API on the browser.***

The server is a Nucleo board (L476RG) with a wifi shield IDW01M1.
The client is Firefox v50.1

**1. Testing the server**

I made Python scripts to establish a WebSocket connection. I noticed that I needed to first "Connect" to the server. Then initiate the exchange after a delay of 600ms
I cannot run my server faster than this. Remember this is a hobby level MCU

**2. Testing the client**

I made a local server using Python. My Javascript client connects to it with no issues.

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u
import socket
import time

TCP_IP = '172.24.220.1'
TCP_PORT = 3000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
#
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect first
connected = False
while not connected:
    try:
        s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
        connected = True
    except Exception as e:
        pass

#------------------------------------
time.sleep(0.6)
#------------------------------------

# Send first bytes
s.send("Good-hi")
# Ping pong
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Same issue happens with Python also when using the WebSocket library

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u
import time
import websocket
from websocket import create_connection

remote = "ws://172.24.220.1:3000"

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect(remote) #<------Need to add delay inside this method

print "WebSocket established"
ws.close()
```

This [page](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#the-websocket-interface) explains what happens inside the WebSocket method. 
With Python I can open a socket without any handshake (RAW Socket), then start my handshake by sending manually the headers. 
However this is impossible to do in a browser because I can't open RAW sockets.
At least, this is my understanding so far.

***Summary***, is there a way to first establish a connection between client and server, then start the handshake at will ?

Comment: Can you post code of you Python Client pls. :D

Comment: @PhilPoore done. I have to mention though: I did not use the "websocket" library on py, because it has the same problem, the handshake happends too fast.

Comment: hmmm.... im confused, you have the 600ms delay in the code above.
which is the code that needs slowing down?

Comment: @PhilPoore, I made that code as a sanity check for the server. That code proves to me that my server is alive (if I wait 600ms). Please refer to the last added code and paragraph: my problem is that I cannot add a 600ms delay in either the Javascript nor Python WebSocket libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the WebSockets api in javascript.

There is a `onopen` event that gets fired when the connection is ready.
you could put a `setTimeout` inside this to delay sending first data.

I don't think you can delay the handshake itself.

Maybe try putting `new Websocket` inside `setTimeout` to make sure all files have been served before trying to start connection.

more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: thanks. onopen is never called: because once new Websocket is called, it will send the headers and await the response from the server. the problem is that the server is not yet ready so misses the transmission completely.  Putting new WebSocket inside a timeout does not do anything. I need to control when the headers are sent by "new WebSocket"